# What font is this? Or is it even a font?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, font-identification, minimalistic

I am not sure if it's okay to a question here like "what font is this?" so sorry if this question is against the guidelines. I keep seeing this type of font everywhere on the logos. Is it even a font or is it just letters modified as objects in Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: FYI, these are the guidelines for font identification questions: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recognise any standard fonts such as this. But you can categorise it under `stencil fonts` as there are no loops involved.
Such style is preferred for either of the two reasons -

- to take advantage of stencil fonts and easily spray-print everywhere for advertisement/publicity.
- for its minimalistic and geometric nature which gives it a professional "simple yet sharp" impression.

You may use free online tools like [whatthefont!](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to search matching fonts.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll look into stencil fonts. I couldn't use whatthefont! because it is an svg image not text, forgot to mention that.

Comment: You can take a screenshot and upload on whatthefont, they accept images in .jpg and .png formats. I did this one for you and the closest one i found is [Pirulen Font](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/pirulen/regular/)

Comment: Didn't know that's possible. Thank you for the info